# macOS: Copy custom text to clipboard on Cmd-C

Tags: swift, macos, copy, uipasteboard

I'd like to be able to copy text to the clipboard when the user does cmd-C using Swift on macOS.

I'm assuming UIPasteboard is involved, but I'm not sure how to intercept the cmd-c command and insert the custom text to the clipboard.

Comment: In macOS `NSPasteBoard` is involved and your question needs more information about what you are going to accomplish.

Comment: The user press cmd-C - how can I copy, e.g. "This is a test" to the clipboard?